# How to make the button visible and hidden according to requirement

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display the button only when $safe_cus is 1.But the button gets displayed when the browser is resized.

```
<?php if($safe_cus == 1) {?>

                <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
                  <div class="pull-right">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo $action_multiple; ?>"><?php echo $button_multiple_bill_payment; ?></a>
                  </div>
            </div>;
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Check your js codes.

Comment: @u_mulder I havent writen any js code.Can you give me a hint  on how to do it

Comment: Obviously, I gave you a hint. If button is not visible on page load, but becomes visible on page __resize__ - then search for js code which executes on resize event.

Comment: `hidden-xs` hides the element on small viewports, shows it on every other

Comment: How can i display it for safe_cus =1 for all screen size and hide it for all other cases

Comment: Just remove the `hidden-xs` class

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use a client-side method because any (web) savvy person can view the HTML source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one more thing you can do is write CSS based on your condition for ex

```
if($safe==1){.css{display:none;}}else{.css{display:blockl}}
```

Now put CSS as a class on your button

hope this helps you.

Comment: Is that valid PHP? Where does `$safe` come from? `blockl` is not a valid display value

Comment: $safe is just a dummy variable you can use your own variable to test that condition.

Comment: as per question, you can use $safe_cus to test it

Answer (score 0):

u can use javascript:
first set an id for your div;
for example "parentdiv"
then get your div to you javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("parentdiv");
```

and set an onload function for ur body tag:
body onload="show()"

then you can do ur display stuff with php:

```
    <?php if($safe_cus == 1) {?>

            <div class="col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
              <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php echo $action_multiple; ?>"><? 
   php echo $button_multiple_bill_payment; ?></a>
              </div>
        </div>;
       <script>
           function show(){
          var div = document.getElementById("parentdiv");
             div.style.display="block";
   }
    </script>
     <?php } ?>
```

Comment: it gets the element from html to javascript so he can use display it